# Starting with ember, route not displaying

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am studying Ember and just started the tutorial on the website, and I m a bit lost with the router concept.

I used the ember router generation, and it worked great.

I have now in app folder :

**./router.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('toto', {path: '/toto'});
});

export default Router;
```

**./templates/toto.hbs**

```
<h1>Toto page</h1>
```

**./routes/toto.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

When i try to access my http://url.com/toto, it displays me the default `application.hbs` template view;

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you have a application.hbs template? It should have {{outlet}} inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember router builds final view as a tree and the root of the tree is always the application route. So now you have two routes: `application` and `toto`. And Ember router renders them one by one. It builds template for `toto` route and tries to append it to the `outlet` of the parent route template which is `application` in your case. Assuming that, is there `{{outlet}}` in your `application.hbs`? If not then you have to put it to the appropriate place.

Also [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi) is very usefull for debugging Ember applications. It can show you which routes are rendered, which templates, components, controllers, etc are used.